# List comparison not working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an application that reads two text files, takes the two, and merges them into one single list. Then take said list, and compare it to another list (from another text file). The problem is that no matter what I do my program always goes to `else` (see the line where it says

```
if (BoysAndGirlsList.Contains(NameEntered) && MostPopularNamesList.Contains(NameEntered))
```

). I don't know why it does this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq; //Needed for concat.

namespace Name_Search
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string BoyNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Google Drive\Course Work\C# Intro\Student Sample Programs\Chap07\BoyNames.txt"); //Reads BoyNames txt file.
            List<string> BoyNamesList = BoyNames.Split('\n').ToList(); //Converts it to a list.
            //BoyNamesList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); <-Testing to make sure that the list is working properly.

            string GirlNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Google Drive\Course Work\C# Intro\Student Sample Programs\Chap07\GirlNames.txt"); //Reads GirlNames txt file.
            List<string> GirlNamesList = GirlNames.Split('\n').ToList(); //Converts it to a list.

            List<string> BoysAndGirlsList;

            BoysAndGirlsList = BoyNamesList.Concat(GirlNamesList).ToList(); //Adds the lists together.
            //BoysAndGirlsList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); <-Again just testing that the list is working.

            string MostPopularNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Google Drive\Course Work\C# Intro\Student Sample Programs\Chap07\MostPopularBoyAndGirlNames.txt"); //Reads MostPopularBoyAndGirlNames txt file. Compiled from http://goo.gl/1crLcY.)
            List<string> MostPopularNamesList = MostPopularNames.Split('\n').ToList(); //Converts it to a list.

            string NameEntered = nameInput.Text;

            if (BoysAndGirlsList.Contains(NameEntered) && MostPopularNamesList.Contains(NameEntered))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This name is one the most popular names!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not one of the most popular names.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What is not working properly here? I've tried putting in a break, and when I did the values looked fine to me.

Comment: For a start, you should *debug* your program and check if the lists actually contain the name you entered. Note that any additional whitespace will prevent the check from being successful.

Comment: @poke Come to think of it when I was testing earlier (checking for console output) I did notice some console white spaces. How would I ensure that DOESN'T happen?

Comment: @Nitsha: You can call `.Trim()` on a string to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: You could trim the input and the items in the list.

Comment: An easy explanation could be that the file has Windows newlines, so splitting by `\n` will not get rid of the `\r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably solved as mentioned by the comments, where redundant spaces in the 'names' causes them to compare unequally. You also have an issue when you want to compare names in a case-insensitive manner.

The first issue can be solved by trimming whitespace from each name:

```
BoysAndGirlsList = BoysAndGirlsList.Select(name => name.Trim()).ToList();
MostPopularNamesList = MostPopularNamesList.Select(name => name.Trim()).ToList();
```

The second issue can be solved by using an invariant case comparer:

```
if (BoysAndGirlsList.Contains(NameEntered, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && 
    MostPopularNamesList.Contains(NameEntered, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: The white space removal worked great, but what does that new if statement do differently? I checked if my if statement worked, and it does.

Comment: @Nitsha It compares using invariant case, such that if the user types "nitsha" in the textbox then it finds "Nitsha" in the lists, whereas your original `if` would not find it as it only compares equal if you get the capitalisation correct. I mostly added that part as a suggestion: you can use it if you think it's useful, or keep using your `if` you don't need it.